# Android Application, Activities, and UI Thread

Tags: android

I'm working on an Android project that consists of several different Activities all associated with the same Application.  We have some common tasks coded in the Application so that we don't have to duplicate them, and one of these tasks is regularly verifying a TCP connection to a dedicated server -- a heartbeat, I suppose.

If it's detected that the connection to the server is lost, I need to notify the user and I'd like to do this in a way that doesn't require me to check all the possible activities to see which is currently "on top".

Is there a way to call runOnUiThread() on whatever activity may be on the UI thread without knowing it explicitly??

Thanks,
R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notify your Activities by sending Intent and registering BroadcastReceiver in each Activity you want to be notified.

service or application can be your context:

```
Intent i = new Intent("MY_ACTION_FROM_SERVICE_STRING");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private ActivityBroadcastReceiver recvr;

    public void onReceiveCommand() {
        //do something
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        recvr = new ActivityBroadcastReceiver(this);
        this.registerReceiver(recvr,
            new IntentFilter("MY_ACTION_FROM_SERVICE_STRING"));
    }
}
```

receiver:

```
public class ActivityBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private MyActivity target;
    public ActivityBroadcastReceiver(MyActivity target) {
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        target.onReceiveCommand();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to find an example of how that is done, but I can't find one simple enough for me to understand.  Do you have any suggestions for an example?

Comment: Well, this is certainly more than I understood a little while ago, but you've still got one explicit receiving activity for the broadcast: "target".  Unless I'm not reading it right and onReceiveCommand() is called on every Activity that registers with that INTENT_FILTER??

Comment: no, Activity doesn't react on Intents, only broadcast receiver, which is registered inside Activity

Comment: What I meant was, "How does the sent Broadcast get to ALL of my activities?"  I asked because I'm not sure how you were intending the Broadcast Receiver code to be implemented by each of the Activities.  I think I have a better grip on things now, but I'll know more as I build my test code.

Comment: Each of your activity which is interested in these intents should register broadcast receiver

Comment: One additional question:  I assume that MY_ACTION_FROM_SERVICE_STRING is basically just a name for the broadcast, but shouldn't it be included in ActivityBroadcastReceiver somewhere?

Comment: it's an action string http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28java.lang.String%29 It should be included in IntentFilter As soon as Receiver gets MyActivity as parameter it can register itself for receiving intents:
`this.target=target;
target.registerReciver(this, INTENT_FILTER);` (in constrcutor)

Comment: So what would be an example of INTENT_FILTER?  Is it actually the same as MY_ACTION_FROM_SERVICE_STRING??

Comment: I think that everything is finely described in docs, but I've updated my post http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html#IntentFilter%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Thanks for the extensive help.

Comment: Works great, by the way, and I feel like writing my first broadcast receiver is a substantial accomplishment.

Answer (score 2):

> Regularly verifying a TCP connection

Sounds like this should be implemented using a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)..

If the alert is very simple, and has minimal importance, I would suggest using a [Toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).

If the alert is crucial, but it doesn't require the user's immediate attention, use a [Notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

If the alert demands immediate user attention, you should use a [Dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html). You won't be able to start a dialog directly from a service or broadcast receiver because they don't have a window associated with them, but you can use an intent to start an activity on a new task. You can style the activity to be whatever you want. It could even look like a dialog box (or show a dialog box when it's started). Starting the activity in a new task will make sure the user can navigate back to whatever they're doing.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simple way (which I've adopted for my project too) is to create a base `Activity` class (preferably *Abstracted*) and then make your normal activity classes to `extend` it. By this, you may put a general piece of code in the abstracted class which may help you to detect currently visible activity.

Moreover, you may set a `BroadcastReceiver` in your base activity class which will always be ready to listen broadcasts regardless of setting it individually in your child activities and then set it to listen for broadcasts sent from your tcp thinggy.

Answer (score 0):

Do not do any trickery. Implement Observer pattern, so any activity would register its listener in `onResume()` and unregister in `onPause()` and whatever will happend your `Application` object code needs just to tell about that to registered listeners, no matter what Activity they are in

Comment: Could you provide an Observer pattern example?  I've never heard of such a thing.

Comment: IMHO you can think of it as of listeners, widely used on Android. Define interface (i.e. `OnSomethingChanged`) with one or more methods (like `void onSomethingChanged(... arguments);` you `Application` object should offer methods like `registerOnSomethingChangedListener( OnSomethingChanfed listener)` and `unregisterOnSomethingChngedListener()`. Store registered listeners in i.e. ArrayList etc and when event occurs, just iterate over listeners and call `onSomethingChanged()` method on each of your registered listener.